# How to reset Arduino with ESP shield?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I'm working on the wifi uploading to Arduino over ESP shield (eg. ESP-12). When uploading over USB Arduino IDE resets the boards first (using DTR) and then interacts with the bootloader. How can i control ESP's GPIOs to reset Arduino board with ESP?

Comment: Have you considered using Esp-Link ( https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link ) on your ESP-12? It comes with the "reset" function, built-in (I had succesfully used it).

Comment: Which firmware do you have installed on the shield? If you're using the AT firmware then please post the results of AT+GMR.

Comment: You may probably send something from ESP to Arduino (through serial), that the Arduino will process and issue a software reset by itself?

Comment: @SMFSW - a commanded reset only works if whatever is currently loaded is both non-broken and intended to recognize that command.

Comment: @Chris you're totally right, i put aside the part that arduino is reflashed at this point. Two options then, find out more about the communication of the arduino core software, there may be some builtin commands. Other option with a gpio would be to bypass the reset button of the arduino board with that output from ESP (driven logic low on avr microntroller reset pin).

Comment: There are no "built in commands" of the "arduino core software" and in fact that anything is able to run *at all* depends entirely on the "sketch" loaded.